# Performance PostgreSQL 14 with long running queries causes PG POD MASTER 0 (StatefulSet) to reach MAX CORES

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I'm running My Backend on a physical machine as follows:

- Backend Code in **TypeScript**
- ORM is **Sequelize**
- Kubernetes: **K3S** version **v1.23.14+k3s1** (c62b03fb) go version go1.17.13

My Backend is running `2` PG PODS (Stateful Set) with the following settings:

```
      volume:
        size: 2500Gi
      numberOfInstances: 2
      postgresql:
        parameters:
          effective_cache_size: "105GB"
          effective_io_concurrency: "200"
          listen_addresses: '*'
          log_destination: "stderr"
          logging_collector: "false"
          log_line_prefix: '%t [%p]: [%l-1] [trx_id=%x] user=%u,db=%d'
          log_min_error_statement: "DEBUG1"
          log_error_verbosity: "verbose"
          maintenance_work_mem: "2GB"
          max_connections: "4000"
          max_wal_size: "16GB"
          min_wal_size: "4GB"
          max_worker_processes: "18"
          max_parallel_workers_per_gather: "9"
          max_parallel_workers: "18"
          max_parallel_maintenance_workers: "4"
          random_page_cost: "1.1"
          shared_bufIfers: "35GB"
          shared_preload_libraries: "pg_stat_statements"
          synchronous_commit: "false"
          syslog_facility: "LOCAL0"
          syslog_ident: "postgres"
          syslog_sequence_numbers: "true"
          syslog_split_messages: "true"
          wal_buffers: "16MB"
          work_mem: "300kB"
          checkpoint_completion_target: "0.9"
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: 20000m
          memory: 140Gi
        requests:
          cpu: 20000m
          memory: 140Gi
```

After around 2 Hours of running stress on the Backend , when I run the following PSQL Code:

```
SELECT
  pid,
  user,
  pg_stat_activity.query_start,
  now() - pg_stat_activity.query_start AS "QueryRunningTime",
  query,
  state,
  wait_event_type,
  wait_event
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE (now() - pg_stat_activity.query_start) > interval '5 minutes'
ORDER BY "QueryRunningTime" DESC;
```

I get queries that take very long , such as :

```
pid              | 5537
user             | postgres
query_start      | 2023-01-02 13:15:45.801772+00
QueryRunningTime | 00:38:24.34075
query            | INSERT INTO "employeesDetails" ("deviceId","employeeId","depId","version","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (............... ,'2023-01-02 13:15:45.824 +00:00','2023-01-02 13:15:45.824 +00:00') ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING "deviceId","employeeId","depId","version","createdAt","updatedAt";
state            | idle
wait_event_type  | Client
wait_event       | ClientRead
```

This query took around `00:38:24.34075` Minutes which is a crazy amount of time.

The PG Pool for each POD is:

```
sequelize:
  pool:
    max: 30
    min: 10
    evict: 1000
    idle: 5000
    acquire: 10000
```

Why is this happening , what makes the queries to run this long even though Sequelize uses the above params ?

It causes my PG to reach MAX Cores after around 3-6 Hours of running.

Answer (score 1):

The shown data from pg_stat_activity does **not** show a long running query.

The connection's state is `idle`. So that connection is not doing anything and is waiting for a new command from the client (=your application).

The content of the `query` column only shows a running query if the state is `active`. Otherwise it merely shows the most recent query that was run in that session.

You can also check `state_change` to see when that session changed into the state you are currently seeing.

But you can not derive the query's runtime by looking at a snapshot of pg_stat_activity (you could, if you took samples of that view frequently and then detect the moment where the state goes from idle to active and back to idle).

The data shown from `pg_stat_activity` is **not** the reason why your connection pool is exhausted. Most likely your application code doesn't properly return connections to the pool. But this does not look like a problem in Postgres.